# play() promise doesn't resolve

Tags: javascript, promise, video.js

I have multiple videos on my site which I need to play().
As play() returns a promise I created a little script using `Promise.all()`, so each promise waits for the others.

```
try {
    var fn = function playVideo(element) {
        var newPromise = element.play();
        console.log('PROMISE', newPromise); // promise is returned (but not yet resolved)
        return newPromise;
    };

    var promise = this.videos.map(fn);
    var results = Promise.all(promise); // all promises should resolve

    results.then(data =>
        console.log('DATA', data)
    ), (err => {
        console.log('error', err);
    });
}
catch(err) {
    console.log('err', err);
}
```

`this.videos` is an array of videos which I define like this:

```
var getVideos = document.querySelectorAll('.project__video .video-js');

if(getVideos.length === 0) {
    return;
}

Array.from(getVideos).forEach((element) => {
    try {
        const autoplay = !element.classList.contains('video-nonplay');
        const controls = !autoplay;
        const muted = autoplay;
        const loop = autoplay;

        const video = window.videojs(element, {
            controls,
            autoplay: false,
            preload: 'none',
            muted,
            fluid: true,
            playsinline: true,
            loop
        });

        if (autoplay) {
            this.videos.push(video);
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log('error while initiating video!', err);
    }
});
```

I expected `Promise.all()` to resolve my promises but instead when I `console.log(data)` I get an array with 2x undefined in Chrome/Safar and no return (.then is never called?) at all in Firefox.

Does this kind of promise resolving not work with .play() or have I done a mistake?

**EDIT 1**

Just noticed, that in Chrome/Safari the video playback is actually started, even though the promise is not resolved. In firefox the playback doesn't start.

**EDIT 2**

Tried to implement solution of Josh Kelly as follow:

Created a separate function called `playVideos`

```
playVideos(videos) {
    try {
        const playVideo = (el) => el.play();
        return videos.map(playVideo);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('err', err);
    }
}
```

I call it like this

```
var vids = this.playVideos(this.videos);
console.log('returned vids', vids);
```

in the console log I can see that chrome has resolved the promise while firefox (and IE/EdgeHTML) have not.

Comment: I would resolve the promise inside of `playVideo()` and return it. You can then delete `Promise.all()` and return the results.

Comment: I tried using `Promise.resolve(newPromise);` but nothing changed. 
Also the docs say, that the promise should automatically resolve when playback has started: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/play

Comment: What are you expecting to be in `data`? According to [video.js docs](https://docs.videojs.com/player#play) the Promise returned by `.play()` does not resolve with anything, so logging undefined is expected. What firefox version are you on?

Comment: @Klaycon shouldn't `data` return the promise itself? so using `console.log(data)` I should see if the promise is fullfilled/resolved. Which currently it isn't (see EDIT 2 and comments on answer below)

Comment: @Toby Read the docs on Promise.all - it takes an array of promises, and returns a promise that will resolve with an array of all the values the promises resolved with once they're all done.

Comment: @Klaycon okay, so I understand that `data` is the returned array and so in Chrome all promises were resolved, while in firefox and IE/Edge some of the promises don't get resolved, but also I don't get any error. Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do something like this below?

an implicit return should resolve the promise for you and then you can return the `videos` with the `playVideo()` method passed in.

```
try {
  const playVideo = (el) => el.play()

  return this.videos.map(playVideo)
} catch(err) {
  console.log('err', err);
}
```

Comment: I have different behaviors in Chrome and Firefox (like described in my EDIT above). Chrome does indeed resolve the promise and play(). Firefox does not resolve the promise.
I will update my question with your code, so you can see how exactly I tried to implement it.